# Append element in DOM from array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h2>Hello {{item.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

My items:

```
items = [
    {
      name: 'David',
      star: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'George',
      star: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'Michael',
      star: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Tim',
      star: 1
    },
]
```

They render:

```
Hello Tim
```

etc.

How to add:

```
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

above **h2**
when  in array:

```
star: 1
```

etc?
Something like this:

```
if (this.items.star == 2) {
   <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
}
```

(It's just an example "if statement" to understand what's going on)

My PLUNKER:
https://plnkr.co/edit/lfZT6FwenhYkQf1MUx9E?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*ngIf` template decorator this way:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <i class="fa fa-star" *ngIf="item.star === 1></i>
  <h2>Hello {{item.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

[See more examples and read more about it here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

> *ngIf: Conditionally includes a template based on the value of an expression.